# Executing AutoLogon.exe via command line with "disable" parameter

Tags: cmd, administration, autologin

Is it possible?
I am looking for something like this:

```
AutoLogon.exe username domain password /disable
```

or

```
AutoLogon.exe /disable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that you can't disable autologin this way. However, you can simply modify the REGISTRY by executing this code as administrator:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
```

Comment: Yes, but the encrypted password for this account will stay in registry forever :/